# motion detection 'if ''sentence

Tags: c#, grammar

I've been writing this motion detecton prog, and met with a problem with 'if sentence', here's the code:

```
       for (int i = 0; i < frameSize; i++, backFrame++, currFrame++)
            {
                // difference
                diff = ((int)*currFrame) - ((int)*backFrame);
               // threshold
                if ((diff >= differenceThreshold) || (diff <= differenceThresholdNeg))
                {
                    *currFrame = (byte)255;
                    if (i < 640)
                    {
                        x[i] = i;
                        y[i] = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        x[i] = i % 640;
                        y[i] = i / 640;
                    }
                    if (xMax < x[i]) xMax = x[i];
                    if (xMin > x[i]) xMin = x[i];
                    if (yMax < y[i]) yMax = y[i];
                    if (yMin > y[i]) yMin = y[i];
                    xC = ((xMax - xMin) / 2) + xMin;
                    yC = ((yMax - yMin) / 2) + yMin; 
                }
                else
                {
                    *currFrame = (byte)0;
                }
             }
```

the problem is that it skips the code after 'if' and do the 'else' even when the condition

```
(((diff >= differenceThreshold) || (diff <= differenceThresholdNeg))) is true.
```

I am new to C# so could anyone help me out?

Comment: Why not simply if (diff >= differenceThreshold || diff <= differenceThresholdNeg)

Comment: How do you determine whether the condition is true? Do you have debug output or a breakpoint? You could try to set differenceThreshold and differenceThresholdNeg to 0, then the condition is always true, annd the code in the the if block should execute.

Comment: thanks, man! so there's no grammatic mistakes here? i did what you said and it worked out. i debugged step by step so i know that, but maybe i was wrong.